# What is the difference between Kony Visualizer & Kony Fabric & Kony Studio

Tags: temenos-quantum

I'm a new developer on Kony and want to build a mobile application deals with database by SOAP web services. which the best for me among these options and what the difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

Details on the Kony product lines can be found on the Kony product pages.  Kony Visualizer is the application design & development platform for creating the "front end" of the app.  Kony Mobile Fabric is the platform for integrating app with backends through middleware services - the product is categorized as a "MBaaS" or "Mobile Backend as a Service".  With Mobile Fabric, you would create integration services that integrate with your backend SOAP, XML, Java, Rest services (along with many more), and then in Visualizer would map the service outputs to your front end.

More information on Visualizer can be found at:
http://www.kony.com/products/visualizer

And Mobile Fabric at:
http://www.kony.com/products/mobilefabric

Please note that Kony Studio is no longer a Kony product.  Kony Visualizer Enterprise now includes the Visualizer app design capabilities, along with the IDE functions formerly a component of Kony Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Kony Studio, until version 6.* was the IDE to code (Android, iOS, Windows) app in JavaScript or Lua.

Starting from Kony Visualizer 7.*, this was the new IDE to code (Android, iOS, Windows) app in JavaScript or Lua.

With Kony Visualizer 7.* came the Kony Mobile Fabric 7.* where you can now easyly deploy web services (Java, WSDL, etc.) or orchestrate JSON cloud services.